# Is it possible to have a DateTime mapper for every underlaying RDBMS?

Tags: php, datetime, pdo, rdbms

I am trying to develop my own ORM Framework on top of `PDO` that follows the Active Record concept and is easy to use. As diving into it, I figured out, that every relational database have its own understanding of date and time data types. I would like to use in my ORM only PHP's `DateTime` and map it down to the underlaying RDBMS, so that we can use the advantages of those data types. But I am not sure, if it is possible, just think of comparsion between a period and so on. Actually, that's also where Doctrine's DBAL seems not to care about. They just say `not supported` on the different data types for date and time when it comes into the differences.

What I want is something like this:

```
MySQL:      PHP DateTime => maps to MySQL DateTime field
PostgreSQL: PHP DateTime => maps to a splitted date field and a time field
Oracle:     PHP DateTime => maps to TIMESTAMP
...
```

The user should be able to set his DateTime field with a setter method on that relational object. When the select, insert, update or delete is executed, it should be mapped to that underlaying maybe splitted date and time field. The same should appear if the user requests that value via the getter method.

Please tell me how it is possible and please also provide a few examples. Thanks a lot! :-)

Edit: I played a bit around with the adapter solution as mentioned below. I think this solves the issue:

```
<?php
namespace Diana\Core\Persistence\Sql\Dbal\Gateway;

interface IAdapter
{
    /**
     * Drills an DateTime instance down to underlaying RDBMS date and time string.
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     * @return string
     */
    public function drillDownDateTime(\DateTime $date);


    /**
     * Parse the RDBMS rows back to an DateTime instance.
     *
     * @param array $rows
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function parseDateTime(array $rows);
}


<?php
namespace Diana\Core\Persistence\Sql\Dbal\Gateway;

class OracleAdapter implements IAdapter
{
    const FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i:s e';
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function drillDownDateTime(\DateTime $date)
    {
        return $date->format(self::FORMAT);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function parseDateTime(array $rows)
    {
        return \DateTime::createFromFormat(self::FORMAT, $rows[0]);
    }
}

<?php
namespace Diana\Core\Persistence\Sql\Dbal\Gateway;

class PostgreSqlAdapter implements IAdapter
{
    const FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i:s e';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function drillDownDateTime(\DateTime $date)
    {
        return $date->format(self::FORMAT);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function parseDateTime(array $rows)
    {
        return \DateTime::createFromFormat(self::FORMAT, $rows[0]);
    }
}
```

As I found in documentation in

[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG238)

[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)

[PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html)

This should work. In MySQL the timezone is a setting in database, so nothing that we can take care about. It is also just an example. But these files in the finished version will be soon part of my [framework](https://github.com/alpham8/dianaphp-framework). Due to my own Date class, which automatically figures out the local date string when outputting, we use `DateTime` as a paramter here, so that both can be passed in.

Comment: I would think that all three support unix timestamps. That may be worth exploring.

Comment: I have already looked. The timestamps differs, too. Some uses UNIX epoch, other uses timestamps since the Nativity as their year 0, etc.. And I am not sure how they are saved to database. Because usually timestamps does not care about leap years and daylight saving time, etc..

Comment: Kind of explains Doctrine's approach then :)

Comment: The one date/time storage that will always work in every system is a Unix timestamp as an integer.  Do not worry about native storage in different formats because most DBs have native functions that can work with timestamps, and you can use simple math for many cases.  Timezone is a separate issue that can be stored in a separate field.  Makes your code very simple and universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an adapter interface!

```
<?php

interface DbAdapterInterface
{
    /**
     * @param DateTime $date
     * @return string
     */ 
    public function convertFromDateTime(DateTime $date);

    /**
     * @param DateTime $date
     * @return array
     */ 
    public function convertToDateTime(array $row);
}

class MySqlAdapter implements DbAdapterInterface
{
    public function convertFromDateTime(DateTime $date)
    {
        return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }

    public function convertToDateTime(array $row)
    {
        return new DateTime($row['date']);
    }
}

class OracleAdapter implements DbAdapterInterface
{
    public function convertFromDateTime(DateTime $date)
    {
        return $date->getTimestamp();
    }

    public function convertToDateTime(array $row)
    {
        return new DateTime('@'.$row['date']);
    }
}

class Db
{
    /** @var DbAdapterInterface $adapter */
    private $adapter;

    public function setAdapter(DbAdapterInterface $adapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
    }

    public function insert($data)
    {
        $date = $data['date'];
        $dateString = $this->adapter->convertFromDateTime($date);
        // do your insert
        return $dateString;
    }

    public function findById($id)
    {
        // fetch row by id here, this is just an example, I'm using the id as the date string
        $row = ['date' => $id];
        $row = $this->adapter->convertToDateTime($row);
        // do your insert
        return $row;
    }
}


// Example

$data = [
    'date' => new DateTime(),    
];

$db = new Db();
$db->setAdapter(new MySqlAdapter());
echo $db->insert($data)."\n";
$db->setAdapter(new OracleAdapter());
echo $db->insert($data)."\n";

$time = '1493308146';
var_dump( $db->findById($time));

$db->setAdapter(new MySqlAdapter());
$time = '2014-09-18 22:00:00';
var_dump( $db->findById($time));
```

See here for a working example: https://3v4l.org/pYgbE

Comment: Ok, thanks, that solves one direction. But I need it bidirectional. I mean, converting a date and time field from database back to PHP DateTime object. This interface architecture is an great idea. Please edit your answer a bit to fit fully my needs.

Comment: I added another interface method, and updated the answer. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your engagement. But I am currently not sure, if this really solves my problem. I will now try to explain to you in otherr words, what I need: Basically, I need an abstraction layer, so that the programmer only deals with `DateTime` objects for `CRUD` interactions with the underlaying database. This means, that the mapper should split it into date and time, if needed and should merge it again together, when the data was read and is ready to build up again into `DateTime` objects, so that it fits into its ORM class attribute again.

Comment: Another point: Is there a possibility to calculate correct from UNIX `Timestamp` back to an `DateTime` object? I mean, as far as I know, when you calculate periods between with `Timestamp`s it is impossible to get an accurate date, only nearly, but not exact, because `Timestamp`s don't take care about leap-years and so on. This might be a point in your solution, that has not been solved, yet. Please show me how or explain it to me. Any ideas on this point are welcome.

Comment: @delboy1978uk You have to care for the timezone too. `converToDateTime()` needs an optional second timezone parameter. But nice solution, nevertheless.

Comment: This is a really nice package for dealing with date ranges, have a look http://period.thephpleague.com/

Comment: just use $date->format() to split your date and time into some private vars